# Axios POST executing the error block with CORS Request and browser dev tools showing 200

Tags: reactjs, cors, axios

I am experiencing strange issue with Axios post while doing CORS Requests.

When i make the call using the following code

```js
export function loginUser (props) {
 var request = axios.post(Endpoints.LOGIN_URL,
  {
   'username': props.username,
   'password': props.password
  });
 return dispatch => {
  dispatch(login())
  return request.then(
   function (response) {
    console.log('success ', response)
    dispatch(loginSuccessful(response.data))
    history.go('/home');
   })
   .catch(function (response) {
    console.log('error', response)
    dispatch(loginFailed(response.data))
   })
 }
}
```

When i execute this i am seeing the Response with 200 Status code in Dev Tools. The pre-flight options request and the subsequent response are working as expected. How ever the Code block that is getting executed is the catch block !!

In console i am getting the following error:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/auth/login. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

In Dev tools i am getting:
[image]
[image]

Not sure why the CORS error in the console even though the Pre-Flight response has the Header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" !!

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header must be present in the **response** from http://localhost:8080/auth/login **POST** operation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your Access-Control-Allow-Origin is specifying port 3000 and you are connecting on port 8080.  Try removing the port entirely so your allow origin header is http://localhost or even set it to * for testing.